# Using Toast with BufferedReader

Tags: java, android, tcp, alert, toast

I hope you can help.

Basically I want to send what ever the "BufferedReader" reads to a Toast, but I have never used Toast before and can't seem to get my head around it.

As you can see below, BufferedReader is "In".

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
package com.smarte.smartipcontrol;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class IPControl extends Activity {

private Socket socket;
private static final int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 32;
public PrintWriter out;
public BufferedReader in;
public String data;
public Object pd;
Intent intent;
String actu_ip; 
String textStatus;

public void getModel(View view) {
    try {
        out.println("[m\r\n");
        //System.out.print("root\r\n");
        while(!in.ready());
        textStatus = readBuffer();

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


//get the message from intent   
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    actu_ip = intent.getStringExtra(IPEntry.ACTUALSMARTIP);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_ipcontrol);

    try {
        new AsyncAction().execute();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) { 
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(actu_ip);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            out = new PrintWriter(bw, true); 
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while (! in .ready());
            readBuffer();
            out.println("root\r\n");
            while (! in .ready());
            readBuffer();
            out.println("root\r\n");
            while (! in .ready());
            String msg = "";
            while ( in .ready()) {
                msg = msg + (char) in .read();
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;//returns what you want to pass to the onPostExecute()
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //results the data returned from doInbackground

        IPControl.this.data = result;

    }
}

private String readBuffer() throws IOException {
    String msg = "";

    while(in.ready()) {
        msg = msg + (char)in.read();
    }
    //System.out.print(msg);
    if(msg.indexOf("SNX_COM> ") != -1) return msg.substring(0, msg.indexOf("SNX_COM> "));
    else if(msg.indexOf("SCX_COM> ") != -1) return msg.substring(0, msg.indexOf("SCX_COM> "));
    else return msg;
}
}
```

Comment: So are you having trouble getting useful text out of your BufferedReader, or are you having trouble creating a Toast? If your answer is "both", I would suggest you start smaller: break the problem into smaller steps and solve each independently and only then should you integrate them together. (This will be a general theme throughout your development career.)

Comment: @mah Hi Mah, my problem is the Toast part. I want to send whatever BufferReader reads to Toast. I will be sorting out the Useful data much later in the App.

Comment: in that case, see codeMagic's answer, and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toast just displays a message on the screen with

`Toast.makeText(context, message to display, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

In your IPControl activity, put this somewhere like in your `onCreate` and you will see what a Toast does

`Toast.makeText(IPControl.this, "Thanks for stopping by!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

In `onPostExecute()` try

`Toast.makeText(IPControl.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: +1 for the one-liner Toast example, which seems to be exactly what the OP is in need of. I would recommend though that you edit out the content after that example since it has nothing to do with anything the OP has asked or implied in his code and therefore just confuses the answer.

Comment: @mah Thank you and I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you are referring to. If you explain better I will do so if it is confusing. I was offering ways to store the data which I think is what the OP is wanting to do.

Comment: I mean everything startting from "This isn't what you want if you are wanting to store the data"; storage of data was never brought up and I'm failing to see any reason why you would infer that it's relevant, so my opinion is that you should delete reference to database, sharedprefs since it isn't related / useful towards the question.

Comment: @mah ok, I will edit after I explain why I thought it was relevant. I added it because I thought they were wanting to store the data and thought that was what a toast was for since "I will be sorting out the Useful data much later in the App" they want to send the data to a toast. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @codeMagic Hi, thanks for your suggestion. No I don't need to store any data just display it on a Toast.

Comment: No problem, hope it makes sense now. My fault for making assumptions

Comment: It made sense in the 1st place. I think Mah might of got confused with himself. Thanks guys.

Comment: @codeMagic How would I link this to my BufferedReader though?

Comment: Put it in your onPostExecute() and use the result as your message to display should work. Or, after it finishes you can read it from your main activity and display it then using that context

Comment: @codeMagic Thanks, not quite there with the "result", just displays an empty box, but I do understand Toast a lot better now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are returning null in `doInBackground` instead of a string result